# Genymotion is not working with my new android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, genymotion, android-studio-3.0

My system uses an ARM processor, hence the default emulator is not compatible. So I installed genymotion. After installing the genymotion, and the plugin, the plugin icon is not displaying. But it displays in my list of device, but when I choose it, my app does not display in my emulator. Please help me. Same issue with nox player

Comment: Hello, please open https://stackoverflow.com/help center and review the topics how to ask and providing information to your question.

Comment: Sorry, any issue with the question I asked?